# Azure App Service, SQL Database: Data rollback issues

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-appservice

Our problem is follow:

1. We have an Azure App Service and Azure SQL Database.  Recently, we have a problem of data missing from the SQL Database.  The App Service was running and the users could create and retrieve the records from App Service.  However, when we did a select statement using SSMS, the record could not be found.  The next day, record cannot be seen via App Service as well.
2. We also have Azure Function App which was running during the same problematic period, but there was no issues with the updating.  All records were updated into the database successfully.

Does anyone having similar problem?  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems like with User permission for Azure SQL Server user. If the user is able to update it looks like he has only updating permission in the schema. I suggest you to cross-check the User permission on table(s) and schema for better clarity.

Refer below example to create `Login`, `User` and `GRANT` permission:

```
CREATE LOGIN utkarsh WITH PASSWORD = 'Uuxwp7Mcxo7Khy';
USE AdventureWorks;
CREATE USER utkarsh FOR LOGIN utkarsh;
GO
```

Grant Select permission:

`GRANT SELECT TO utkarsh`

Refer: [GRANT Database Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can add a database user to a database role using the following query:

`EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'userName'`

Comment: Hi UtkarshPal-MT， thanks a lot for sharing.  But if this is a permission issue, isn't the problem will occur all the time?  Our problem is the issue only occurred recently (twice already) now for a period of hours, since the App Service was launched 2 years ago.  Appreciate your comment. Thanks